# Binary to Decimal in C++

Tags: c++, binary

```
if(input.is_open() && output.is_open())
{
    while(!input.eof())
    {
        char a=NULL;
        getline(input,line);
        while(!line.empty())
        {
        int num=0;
        string byte=line.substr(0,8);
        for(int i=0;i<byte.length();i++)
        {
            if(byte.at(i)==1)
            {
                num=num+pow(2,8-i);
            }
            else
            {
                num+=0;
            }
        }
        output << num << " ";
        line=line.substr(8);
        }

    }
}
```

I want to read from file which one line is 32 bit binary number take 8 bits from it and transform decimal. But above code give always 0.

Comment: Off topic: `while(!input.eof())` is a bad idea. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Off topic: untested file read: `getline(input,line);` you have no idea whether or not a line was read.

Comment: Off topic: `pow` is overkill here and brutally slow. You can use bit shifting. `num=num +(1 << (8-i));` will set the (8-i)th bit and add it to the current value of num.

Comment: When i debug it, it takes corret line ok als it takes 8 bit from that line, but it cant enter if statement ?

Comment: Apologies. `num=num +(1 << (8-i));` should be `num=num +(1 << (7-i));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what is said in the first answer, you need

```
num=num+pow(2,7-i);  // note 7 instead of 8.
```

This is assuming your input line looks like

```
10101010101010101010101010101010
```

and you want output like

```
170 170 170 170
```

If you are trying to do something else, then please clarify the question.

You may also want to heed the advice of those who commented on your question.

Answer (score 0):

A few things can be fixed, but the main problem is

```
if(byte.at(i)==1)
```

is comparing the character at `i`, a `'1'` (ASCII code 49)  or a `'0'` (ASCII code 48),  against the number 1. So if `byte[i]` is `'1'`, then 49 is compared against 1 and returns false.

Solution:

Compare character with character

```
if (byte.at(i) == '1')
```